# What final test to apply to a permutation test (by compression) algorithm?

Tags: permutation-test, iid

I'm following in the steps of §5.1 Permutation Testing, [NIST Special Publication 800-90B, Recommendation for the Entropy Sources Used for Random Bit Generation](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90B.pdf).

I'm developing my test for identifying IID data, using compression à la §5.1. I compress the original data sample. I then repeatedly shuffle the data and re-compress.  The ratio between the original compressed size and the compressed shuffled sizes is the test metric (correlation factor). And so I get the following for 100 runs:-

[image: scores]

where correlation factor >0 suggests non-IID data, whilst <0 suggests IID data. The pie chart currently ignores any =0's.You can see that approximately 30% of the tests compressed the shuffled data to more than the original un-shuffled sample.

NIST applies a simple binary pass/fail test in accordance with item 3:-

[image: score]

**Q: Is there a $p$ type statistical test that can be applied to the number of higher/lower compressions?**  So for this example, we might say $p=0.x$ that 30 permutations would compress more simply by chance.

---

I'm hoping for something a bit more specific to this question than:
[Test for IID sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/28715/74762), [How to choose the test statistic for permutation test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59638/74762) or [p-values for permutation tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/324154/74762).

In the above example, the data is cryptographic strength IID, so in the long run I would expect a 50% green/red split.